# Reading text with RTL Combination between arabic and english

Tags: java, xml, right-to-left

i've XML file that have tag contains Arabic and English characters but written from left to right, but i want when parsing the XML file and read this tag to read it from right to left because this is only the way i can save the words order.

for example this XML tag

```
<Trxn_Desc_AR><![CDATA[     بمبلغ       0       SAR     فرع     Remote Banking Division     بواسطة      SHORT53488550       رقم العملية     مستحق في        2014-03-26      ]]></Trxn_Desc_AR>
```

i'm reading the XML file as UTF8

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "utf-8");
         BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

your help is really appreciated i've tried a lot of suggestions but still can't fix this problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? In Unicode text is stored with the characters in logical order rather than display order and there are defined algorithms for handling bidirectional display. If you drag over the text to select it you'll see that the selection switches between ltr and rtl as you move between the English and Arabic segments.

Comment: The apparent discrepancies with word order are because some characters like spaces and punctuation are neutral with regards to direction. In a document that is treated as predominantly ltr with some rtl segments, if you have English-Arabic-English then the spaces between a ltr and rtl segment will be treated as ltr, but if you have English-Arabic1-Arabic2 then the spaces between the two Arabic segments will be rtl and it'll display as English-2cibarA-1cibarA

Comment: The question probably is how to display this tag correctly; the answer depends on the medium; e.g. html, or windows text label, etc.

Comment: the problem occurs with me when trying to read the xml tag and write it in text file it didn't appear correct until i switch the text direction manual from the menu option to RTL, if there any way to make the text RTL automaticaly